# Images not showing despite autocomplete confirming my path is correct

Tags: html, css, angular

[Code with file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8UNG.png)

I'm trying to get to images to show on this page. The autocomplete is giving me the path as I go. I'm pretty confident the path is right yet the two images I'm trying to add on this page show as broken.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code and expect people to work out what it is doing.  Not only is it difficult to read code from a picture, but it's possible for the picture to be inaccessible in the future, making the post itself useless.  If the code is relevant to the question, post it as a [mcve] in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete only knows the file path on your local filesystem. This is most likely not the URL it is actually being served at. So you will most likely get the image from the served asset folder on your deployed server. Angular, by default, serves the asset folder on `ng serve`, so the path will be `/assets/images/favicon-16x16.png`.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly it. I was thinking it had to be something with the way the path was once it was running with ng serve. Wasn't aware this was assets by default. Thanks again!